# What are the various availiable types of Cabal Government, and what, if any, is the difference between them?

Tags: the-secret-world

So, I joined a Cabal. As with 'guilds' in most MMO's, there's a rank structure, and a bank, and a Message of the Day.

We also have a 'Type of Government'. I know my Cabal is a *Mobocracy*, and I know making it a *Plato's Republic* was rejected.

I'm assuming my Mobocracy's current rank structure of:

> 1. MobRuler
> 2. Ochlocrat
> 3. Majoritarian
> 4. Crowd member

in descending order is inherited from the type of government. Does the choice of government have any other affects? What's the full list of available government types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different government types are absolutely identical, it's purely for thematic purposes.  (The rank names differ between types.)

The available types are:

- Assembly
- Commune
- Corporation
- Coven
- Directive
- Military Junta
- Ministry
- Mobocracy
- Plato's Republic
- Posse
- Rebellion
- Syndicate
- Technocracy
- Temple
- Tribunal
- Troupe

(I've omitted a complete listing of rank names here for readability purposes; they're all about what you'd expect.)

Comment: Do you have a link to the full listing?

Comment: @Ingmar Unfortunately not.

Comment: [Full list of rank names](http://www.gunbad.com/SWtOR/index.php?topic=1355.0)

Answer (score 2):

Complete list of government types for cabals in The Secret World:

- Assembly
- Commune
- Corporation
- Coven
- Directive
- Military Junta
- Ministry
- Mobocracy
- Plato's Republic
- Posse
- Rebellion
- Syndicate
- Technocracy
- Temple
- Tribunal
- Troupe

(A previous answer left out only one entry: Tribunal)

Comment: I've upvoted you for helpfulness, but in situations like this it usually makes more sense to just edit an existing answer where there's clearly just a textual error.  (I actually copied this out of the game and must have skipped over it)

Answer (score 0):

The government only affects the name of the ranks.

Comment: That is not entirely true, half of them have 4 tiers, the others have 5. however, the 5th rank is mostly useless. See here for a list: http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=35796